# API to find react native version and subversion?

Tags: api, react-native, version

How to find the current/latest available version and subversion of react native from the web? `0.41.0, 0.41.1, 0.41.2` etc

Not this `react-native --version`, as this finds the version of the current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try: `npm show react-native version`. The current result is

```
0.41.2
```